# [self navigationController]pushViewController:

Tags: ios

I have an app with tab and i would load page detail from table list.

In my appDelegate.m i have the function:

```
    @synthesize DetailController = _DetailController;
-(void)loadDetails{
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:_DetailController animated:YES];
}
```

I call from view firstviewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 [[self appDelegate] setCurrentlySelectedBlogItem:[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[self appDelegate] loadDetails];
}
```

but do not change view. Why?

In my appDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FirstViewController;
@class DetailViewController;
@class RSSEntry;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    UIWindow * _window;
    FirstViewController * _viewController;
    UINavigationController * _navigationController;
    DetailViewController * _DetailController;
    RSSEntry * _currentlySelectedBlogItem;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet FirstViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationController * navigationController;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet DetailViewController * DetailController;
@property (readwrite,strong) RSSEntry * currentlySelectedBlogItem;

-(void)loadDetails;

@end
```

Comment: where do you initialize _detailController?

Comment: More information is needed here. Have you initialized the DetailController and the navigationController? Also, the methods to not have the same name.

Comment: your calling `loadNewsDetails` but the declared method is called `loadDetails`. If this isn't just a typo in your question, that would be a problem :)